# Activeup .net : Is it possible to search by Date and Time : hour and minute for mail?

Tags: c#, search, mailsystem.net

I'm using the ActiveUp.Net.Mail to connect gmail and get mails from Inbox . I want to get mails after a specific date , hour and minute . I tryed for a specific date and it worked succesfully but when I added a time on my query it was stopped 
This is my code

```c#
private MessageCollection GetMailsSinceDate(string mailBox , DateTime dt)
        {
            Mailbox mails = Client.SelectMailbox(mailBox);
            MessageCollection messages = mails.SearchParse("SENTSINCE 02-Dec-2014");
            return messages;
        }
```

This code works ,but if I use :

```c#
MessageCollection messages = mails.SearchParse("SENTSINCE 02-Dec-2014 13:07:29");
```

This exception appears : Command "search SENTSINCE 02-Dec-2014 13:07:29" failed : 141202032754582 BAD Could not parse command

Can anyone help me please ! Thanks

Comment: you have to modify the SearchParse method - can you show the method?

Answer (score 0):

can you try something like the following So passing with the Parameter you would do the following

```
 MessageCollection messages = 
      mails.SearchParse("SENTSINCE " 
      + DateTime.Now.ToString(dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
```